# Golang goroutine doesn't run with channel inside

Tags: go

I'm trying to implement a word count program, but with the first step i got some problem.

Here's my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "bufio"
    "sync"
)

// Load data into channel
func laodData(arr []string,channel chan string,wg sync.WaitGroup) {
    for _,path := range arr {
        file,err := os.Open(path)
        fmt.Println("begin to laodData ", path)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            os.Exit(-1)
        }
        defer file.Close()
        reader := bufio.NewReaderSize(file, 32*10*1024)
        i := 0
        for {
            line,err := reader.ReadString('\n')
            channel <- line
            if err != nil {
                break
            }
            i++
            if i%200 == 0 {
                fmt.Println(i," lines parsed")
            }
        }
        fmt.Println("finish laodData ", path)
    }
    wg.Done()
}

// dispatch data lines into different mappers
func dispatcher(channel chan string,wg sync.WaitGroup){
    fmt.Println("pull data 11")
    line,ok := <- channel
    fmt.Println(ok)
    for ok {
        fmt.Println(line)
        line,ok = <- channel
    }
    fmt.Println("pull data 22")
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    path := os.Args
    if len(path) < 2 {
        fmt.Println("Need Input Files")
        os.Exit(0)
    }
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)

    channel := make(chan string)
    defer close(channel)

    fmt.Println("before dispatcher")
    go laodData(path[1:],channel,wg)
    go dispatcher(channel,wg)
    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println("after dispatcher")
}
```

And here's my output:

```
...

finish laodData  result.txt

throw: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [semacquire]:
sync.runtime_Semacquire(0x42154100, 0x42154100)
    /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime/zsema_amd64.c:146 +0x25
sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0x4213b440, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/pkg/sync/waitgroup.go:79 +0xf2
main.main()
    /Users/kuankuan/go/src/mreasy/main.go:66 +0x238

goroutine 2 [syscall]:
created by runtime.main
    /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:221

goroutine 4 [chan receive]:
main.dispatcher(0x42115a50, 0x0, 0x2, 0x0)
    /Users/kuankuan/go/src/mreasy/main.go:45 +0x223
created by main.main
    /Users/kuankuan/go/src/mreasy/main.go:65 +0x228
exit status 2
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Program terminates when main goroutine exits, so that `dispatcher()` has no time to do anything. You need to block in `main()` until `dispatcher()` completes. Channel can be used for this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "bufio"
)

var done = make(chan bool)             // create channel

// Load files and send them into a channel for mappers reading.
func dispatcher(arr []string,channel chan string) {
    for _,path := range arr {
        file,err := os.Open(path)
        fmt.Println("begin to dispatch ", path)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            os.Exit(-1)
        }
        defer file.Close()
        reader := bufio.NewReaderSize(file, 32*10*1024)
        i := 0
        for {
            line,_ := reader.ReadString('\n')
            channel <- line
            i++
            if i%200 == 0 {
                fmt.Println(i," lines parsed")
            }
        }
        fmt.Println("finish dispatch ", path)
    }
    done <- true                 // notify main() of completion
}

func main() {
    path := os.Args
    if len(path) < 2 {
        fmt.Println("Need Input Files")
        os.Exit(0)
    }
    channel := make(chan string)
    fmt.Println("before dispatcher")
    go dispatcher(path[1:],channel)
    <-done                 // wait for dispatcher()
    fmt.Println("after dispatcher")
}
```

Comment: In this precise case it would be simpler to remove `go ` in `go dispatcher(path[1:],channel)`.

Comment: thanks @dystory, i need to do something else beside dispatcher in main thread.

Comment: hi,victor, i followed your advice, but i met a Dead Lock! issue.**throw: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!  channel <- line **

Comment: @MrROY `dispatcher()` sends stuff to a `channel`, passed as it's argument and nobody accepts it on the other end, so it's goroutine is blocked. `main()` is blocked too, because it is waiting for `dispatcher()` to finish.

Comment: Hi,@VictorDeryagin Thanks for your great anwser, but i add a reciever to the channel it still dead lock.

Answer (score 2):

I [modified your example](http://play.golang.org/p/U-Q0-0tX5_) to run on the Go playground where there's no file I/O; it sends random numbers on the channel instead.

@Victor Deryagin's explanation and his suggestion of using a "done" channel is correct. The reason you get a deadlock is that your goroutine sends on channel, but no one reads from it, so the program is stuck at this point. In the above link I added a consumer goroutine. The program then runs concurrently as intended.

Note that to wait for several goroutines, it's clearer and easier to use [sync.WaitGroup](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup).

Answer (score 1):

Two issues needs to be fixed in the original question.

1. You have to close the channel once you're done sending all the data. In func `laodData`, please use close(channel) post sending all data.
2. Pass the `sync.Waitgroup` as a reference.you are sending wg as a value in the argument to the following functions... `laodData` and dispatcher functions.

Fixing these two issues will fix your problem of deadlock. The reasons for the deadlock in your code follow:

- Leaving the  sending channel unclosed will cause the downstream channel to wait for prolonged time.
- sending the argument of `sync.Waitgroup` as a value . It should be sent as a reference otherwise it will create a new copy of the object which you are sending.